If a DC motor accepts a higher and a lower voltage (for 2-speed modes), which speed will have more current drawn?
The load is a DC massage chair motor and nothing else changes when stepping down to the lower voltage (meaning no gear or other mechanical changes that would impact load). Will there be more or less current utilized in the lower voltage (lower speed) mode? I know what current is drawn when using the higher voltage mode, but I need to size out a replacement for the failed step-down transformer (decide on sufficient va rating), so I’d like to determine whether the motor will draw more or less current than what I am reading in the higher voltage mode.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

lower voltage is able to push only lower current through a load

Under the assumption that your load torque remains the same for both load speeds, the motor will draw exactly the same current at a lower voltage.
Take a look at the following example of motor performance at different supply voltages. Changing the supply voltage will not affect the slope of the current curve.



I’d like to determine whether the motor will draw more or less current than what I am reading in the higher voltage mode.

The answer depends entirely on the load and how the torque required varies with the motor rpms. A high voltage could cause the motor with load to rotate rapidly generating a back emf almost equal to the applied voltage. In that case your current might be small. On the other hand, a low voltage could cause your motor to struggle or even stall on the same load. A stalled motor will generate no back emf, so the current through the motor windings can be very large. My guess would be motors that drive conveyor belts or industrial lathes, would have that problem. On the other hand, a motor that drives a small, high rpm fan would probably draw less current with lower voltage.
So, the answer could go either way depending upon specifics.
